# Выбрать все теги для новости

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с новостями и есть таблица с тегами, которая имеет Id новости и имя тега.
Как мне выбрать новость и ее теги одним запросом, отдельно никак...

Comment: лучше всё таки сделать отдельно, ибо иначе либо напряжете сервер бд, либо будете передавать всю новость много раз (сколько тэгов у нее)

как вариант - хранимой процедурой

Comment: @eicto, а юнион или подзапросы не прокатят разве?

Comment: @Sh4dow прокатит, но мне кажется стоимость будет запроса велика, если честно слабо представляю... тэги же надо как-то вернуть через запятую что-ли в поле... mongo мне кажется в этом отношении рулит

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  
        `новости`.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`теги`.`имя` ORDER BY  `теги`.`имя` ASC SEPARATOR  '; ' ) AS  `тэги` 
    FROM
        `новости` 
    LEFT JOIN
        `теги`
            ON (  `новости`.`ID` =  `теги`.`ID_новости` )
    GROUP BY
        `новости`.`ID`
```

Comment: 2 вопроса, ну будет ли этот запрос слишком тяжкий для сервера?
И можно ли как то получить теги в массиве по одному, а не строкой разделенной сепаратором?

Comment: Не тяжелее обычного `JOIN`, а может даже и легче, т.к. за счет `GROUP` возвращаем меньший объем информации. А чтобы получить массив - можно использовать `php explode()`.